# karaf - How to handle: "Error installing bundles"?

Tags: maven, apache-karaf

I created a simple karaf application that just run some calculations.
After that I did `mvn clean install` and then I added the bundle to the local maven repository with `install:install-file -Dfile=bundle1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=prg.ogra -DartifactId=bundle1 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar`

Now I run karaf with `./apache-karaf-4.2.0/bin/karaf debug` and when I do `install mvn:org.orga/bundle1/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

I get an error: `Error executing command: Error installing bundles: Unable to install bundle mvn:org.orga/bundle1/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: mvn:org.orga/bundle1/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

What should I do?
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In karaf, run the following:

```
maven:summary
```

and make sure karaf is actually linked to the correct local repository.

In addition, navigate to your local repository on the file system and verify that the bundle is located at the maven coordinates you are specifying in the install command. Edit as needed.

Comment: `maven:summary  > Command not found: maven:summary
` and when I search to my local repository lib I cannot see my jar even when I follow these steps , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project

Comment: The maven:xxx commands will be part of your Karaf installation, if you have the Karaf maven feature installed. If not, run this command in Karaf: feature:install maven

Comment: when I try to `feature:install maven` I get `Error executing command: Error:
 Error downloading mvn:org.apache.karaf.maven/org.apache.karaf.maven.core/4.2.0
` - @MichaelPeacock